# issues accessing my array variable outside my for loop in python (it only is accessing the last known value)

Tags: python, arrays, scope

I have a python script that get a list of playlists for a youtube channel.
I then pull out the playlist IDs in that channel.
I have created a global array variable to store the playlist IDs in the channel.

here is my code:

```
import urllib
import ast
import os

from io import StringIO
import json
import pprint
import ast


url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UC_ANPr8IkWibKlKhmi_-H1g&key=<my YT API key>"
playlist_array = []
videos_array = []

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
#data = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(response))
data = json.loads(response.read())

print data
pprint.pprint(data['items'])

for item in data['items']:
    print(
        "Title: {}\nid: {}\nurl: {}\n".format(item['snippet']['title'], item['id'], item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url']))

for item in data['items']:
    playlist_id = (json.dumps(item['id'])).strip('"')
    playlist_array = [playlist_id]
    print playlist_array[-1]

print playlist_array[-1]

# now iterate list of playlists to extract the videos in each playlist
##### TO DO Code right here #########
```

When I run the code, i can see all the playlist IDs for the channel when I print the variable *inside* the for loop. When I print the list values of the array variable *outside* the for loop (which I need to access outside the for loop so I can get the video IDs of that particular playlist).

Output from Pycharm:
PLejO9z7yhQOxjONeDVWaAy3kX3tEcImCR
PLejO9z7yhQOwt7OKSMVLdAe4jeYDpZNJC
PLejO9z7yhQOzJ068ZMLd0Zub_FOrGJ82y
PLejO9z7yhQOx8ZrJYJ3o5zckygwvtUb1R
PLejO9z7yhQOxx6XqB6DLvQd0-IDpb299H
***PLejO9z7yhQOxx6XqB6DLvQd0-IDpb299H <---- this is from printing the array variable outside the for loop***

How do I make it so that the array variable is accessible globally to my script?

Thanks.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Note, you are not working with arrays but with *lists*. In any case, you keep assigning a new list to `playlist_array = [playlist_id]` on each iteration, with a single element in it, so of course, there is only that last element from the loop. You need to use `.append`. Quite frankly, this is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in general, you should NEVER use global variables.

That said, as @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, `playlist_array = [playlist_id]` does not add anything to your list - it just creates a new list.

The line you want is:

`playlist_array.append(playlist_id)`.

Comment: Thanks.
This answer was more concise and delivered all the details I needed.